# Pandas: Select rows based on conditions on neighbouring row values

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
from random import randint

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [randint(1, 9) for x in xrange(1000)],
                   'B': ...,
                   'C':....})
```

I want to select the rows that meet the following condition: Row is selected if at least X consecutive neighboring rows (in either direction) have A values that meet the following condition: abs(myRowAValue - meanAValueOfTheXNeighbors ) < Y.

In other words, I want to select rows at places where A values are rather constant.

I am looking for the most efficient "Pandas" way of doing this.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what your expected outcome should look like, but see if this can help you (Probably also not the most efficient and not all Pandas):

```
import pandas as pd
from random import randint
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [randint(1, 9) for x in range(1000)]})
neighbours = 10
tolerance = 2

nparray = np.array(df['A'])
nparray_len = len(nparray)

fbegin = [iterator for iterator, element in enumerate(nparray) if abs(element - np.average(nparray[:iterator+neighbours])) < tolerance and iterator < neighbours]
fmid = [iterator for iterator, element in enumerate(nparray) if abs(element - np.average(nparray[iterator-neighbours:iterator+neighbours])) < tolerance and iterator >= neighbours and iterator <= nparray_len - neighbours]
fend = [iterator for iterator, element in enumerate(nparray) if abs(element - np.average(nparray[iterator-neighbours:])) < tolerance and iterator > nparray_len - neighbours]
IDS = np.unique(np.array(fbegin + fmid + fend))
nparray[IDS]


df_constant = df.iloc[IDS]
print(df_constant)
```